# Not able to calculate BIC in bidirectional stepwise regression in R

Tags: r, bic, stepwise-regression

I am trying to perform stepwise regression with direction as "both" based on BIC in r.

But everytime is performing based on AIC only

Following is my code

```r
train <- read.csv("Regression_train.csv", header=TRUE, 
    stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

test <- read.csv("Regression_test.csv", header=TRUE, 
    stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

fit.all <- lm(joyjoy ~ ., train)

null <- lm(joyjoy ~ 1, train ) 

step(null, scope=list(lower=null, upper=fit.all), 
    criterion = "BIC", direction="both", k = log(n))
```

I don't know why it is performing stepwise bidirectional based on AIC only even though after specifying BIC

Can someone please help here?

Comment: Questions about how to get R to do what you want are off topic here.  They *can* be on topic on [SO], but require a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536) (among other things).

Comment: FWIW, you almost certainly should not use stepwise selection.  It may help you to read my answer to [Algorithms for automatic model selection](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20856/7290).